# PostgreSQL, xamarin forms

Tags: c#, postgresql, xamarin

Делаю проект на xamarin forms, и мне нужно подключить туда удалённую БД PostgreSQL. Установить пакет Npsql и похожие через NuGet не получается из-за несовместимости с xamarin forms. Как мне решить эту проблему?